# Просмотр Ajax данных в Google Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, браузер

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Google Chrome посмотреть данные полученные средствами Ajax?

Т.е. нужно найти исходные данные, которые пришли с сервера(json), а не обработанные js скриптом.

Есть ли поиск по слову?

Comment: во вкладке `Network` появляются отправленные запросы, там же можно посмотреть и ответ `Preview`/`request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F12 вкладка Network там ctrl+f

Answer (score 0):

dev-консоль открывается по клавише F12, ajax-запросы отображаются на вкладке "сеть". Свежие запросы можно посмотреть только с момента открытия консоли, запросы до открытия консоли отображаться на вкладке не будут.